# Integrating TeXlive to ubuntu

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, linux, texlive-2017

I have installed TeXlive from texlive.org and all I need to do now is, too say to my ubuntu system that TeXlive is installed.

I have found [this](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) which says:

> Tell APT about your TeX Live installation by building a dummy package
>   using equivs:

```
$ aptitude install equivs # as root 
mkdir /tmp/tl-equivs && cd /tmp/tl-equivs 
equivs-control texlive-local
# edit texlive-local (see below) 
$ equivs-build texlive-local
$ sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb
```

> At the step "edit texlive-local", edit the Maintainer field and the
>   list of the packages provided by your local TeX Live installation as
>   appropriate. If you installed scheme-full except collection-texinfo as
>   recommended, the file should look like the following example file for
>   TL 2017.

I am a bit new to ubuntu so sorry for the maybe stupid question: I just have to type the six line into the terminal (with that $ signs?) and what do I have to do at the forth line?

Comment: The `$` are prompts. They tell you that this command should be entered as user (without the `$`). The other prompt you see is `#`. Those tell you that this command should be entered with root privileges (without the `#`). Those are the default prompts of `bash`.

Comment: Instead of the `equivs-control texlive-local` step, I usually just download `https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2017-ex.txt` (or the more suitable year), listed on https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html, then save it as `texlive-local`, build and install.

Comment: @daleif Where do you save it and how do you build it and install it? After that you don't need to continue with lines 4-6?

Comment: After performing line 2 in your posted list, run `wget https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2017-ex.txt`, that will save this fir to the folder you are currently in (`/tmp/tl-equivs`), next rename it: `mv debian-equivs-2017-ex.txt texlive-local`, then run the last two lines in your list. Ubuntu till probably complain about missing `freetype` or `glute`, that is solved by running `sudo apt install -f` (this resolves any missing dependencies from the `dpkg` command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment, there is step by step (with no explanations) of what I normally do

```
sudo apt install equivs 
mkdir /tmp/tl-equivs && cd /tmp/tl-equivs 
wget https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2017-ex.txt -O texlive-local
equivs-build texlive-local
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

perform them one line at a time.

In line 3 I used `-O` to specify the name the file should be saved under. Change the URL to something fitting for you (hello future visitor), the link comes from https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html. In the `dpkg` line, the file name should of course be the generated file name.

The last line resolves any dependencies left over by running the `dpkg` command (which cannot resolve dependencies, `apt` can, but `apt` is usually not used to install local packages).

Comment: Thank you, I did it. If I do `tlmgr update --all` now, I got the message that the programm tlmgr is not installed. Is that normal?

Comment: @user372565  First of, these lines only build and install an equivs package, telling Ubuntu that you have installed something equivalent to the Ubuntu `texlive` packages. What you manually installed `texlive`?

Comment: I have manually installed texlive, yes. So if I type `tlmgr update --list`, I get a list with packages for which there is an update. That works. But if I type `tlmgr update --all` I get the message: 
`tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2017/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.`

Comment: But if I type `sudo tlmgr update --all` I get the message that the program `tlmgr` is not installed.

Comment: As part of the installation you added the new TeXLive path somewhere, where exactly did you add that path? When you run `sudo` the path (where the system looks for programmes) is not the same as the path for your user. Also if this is a single person system, you would not install it in `/usr/local/texlive` (as it is owned by root), I typically create `/opt/texlive` and make it owned by me and then install texlive there as me.

Comment: As your user, run `which tlmgr`, then use that full path as your `tlmgr` when using `sudo`. My setup would use `/opt/texlive/current/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`  (current is a small trick)

Comment: I used that [skript](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/4775/neuinstallation-texlive-probleme-mit-babel#4776).

Comment: Interesting, that probably means that this path is not added to the sudo path (you can always whech using `sudo which tlmgr` and `sudo echo $PATH`

Comment: Sudo resets the path to a minimal, one needs to add the path addition to /etc/profile(.d)

Comment: @norbert if the OP did what that link said (skript a few comments above), that seems to add to  etc-profile

Comment: Indeed, it might be that sudo actually ignores also these files and starts with a fixed path. I'm away from my computer in the mountains, but the man passed of sudo should explain that.

Comment: @norbert it's one of the reasons why I never install upstream texlive as root